# Dotnetbrowser - Local Storage not works in VB.NET

Tags: local-storage, dotnetbrowser

I've created a project in VB.NET/dotnetbrowser, that lets player to open a .html Twine game, stored in the VB.NET project debug folder.

Twine engine has a built-in local storage system for save/load. This feature not works in this VB.NET/dotnetbrowser project.

I'm not familiar with this problem, should I turn on local storage option somewhere in dotnetbrowser, or what to do? Any idea?

Thanks, p

Answer (score 0):

It looks that you should use some Chromium switches to enable an access to local files.
Try this code: `BrowserPreferences.SetChromiumSwitches("--disable-web-securi‌​ty", "--allow-file-access-from-files");`

Do not forget that this switchers should be set before you create any Browser instance. This article describes how to set Chromium switchers: https://sites.google.com/a/teamdev.com/dotnetbrowser-support/documentation/chromium-switches

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it did not solve the problem. I read everything I've found but can't figure it out.

Comment: Have you tried to load this web page from your file system into Chromium? Did local storage work as expected in that case? Did you try to use a previous version of DotNetBrowser (ver. 1.9)?